# Inversion of compound tenses after question words like pourquoi, comment, où, etc

Tags: grammaire, interrogative, temps-composés

When inverting compound tenses after question words would you invert it like

> Comment as-tu travaillé comme ça

or

> Comment as travaillé tu comme ça

Because I've seen

> Comment est allé le week-end pour toi

And not

> Comment est le week-end allé pour toi

Comment: Il est intéressant de remarquer qu'on dit "Comment est le week end ?" pourtant...

Answer (score 3):

For compound tenses, you must invert the subject and the auxiliary (*être* or *avoir*).

> Comment a-t-il travaillé ?
> *(the "t" in "a-t-il" is here only for euphonic purposes)*

In many cases, basically every time the subject is not a pronoun, the subject is duplicated using a pronoun.

> Comment la réunion s'est-elle passée ?

In oral or colloquial language, the subject-verb inversion tends to disappear, but for compound tenses it remains, except that the whole verb comes before the subject.

> Comment s'est passée la réunion ?

Except when the subject is a pronoun, then the inversion is most often left aside.

> Comment ça s'est passé ?
>
> Comment il a travaillé ?

These non-inverted phrases are not correct, strictly speaking, and should not be written. However, that's the way most natives would say things orally, so you will see it written as well.

So for your specific examples, the correct phrases would be :

> Comment as-tu travaillé comme ça ?
>
> Comment est allé le weekend pour toi ? *(colloquial)*
>
> Comment le weekend est-il allé pour toi ?

On a sidenote : grammar aside, "how did [...] go ?" would not translate to "comment est allé [...] ?", but rather to "comment s'est passé [...] ?". Your sentence is understandable, but unusual.

Comment: Ah I see, so the inversion is mainly just optional?

Comment: No. The inversion is the rule. We just don't bother with it in **oral** language. In written or formal speech, the inversion is not optional.

Comment: "Comment il a travaillé ?", although (too) common, is definitely not right, even for oral communication...

Comment: Then you speak only with highly educated and formal people ;-) It's definitely not correct, but it's also very definitely used by most.

Answer (score 0):

« Comment as-tu travaillé comme ça » but it's not very meaningful…

For the second one I would say : « Coment s’est passé ton weekend ? »

Comment: So if it's a être passé composé verb you have to put the past participle before the noun?

Comment: So "Pourquoi est allé il" or "Comment est devenu il..."? Or no?

Comment: @chaplinmyflabbydog, not necessarily : « Ton weekend s’est bien passé ? » (exact same meaning)

Comment: "Pourquoi est-il", "Comment est-il" definitively